# How to exchange packets with server in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm still completely newbie at vb.net. I apologize for my english.

I want to get a gameserver information from server. Server is using GameSpy protocol. In order to get information, you will have to send a request. Server will answer to it and you need to send another packet based of this server response. Then server will send you information. I know what packets to send and what is expected to receive, that is not a problem.

I'm stuck in actually receiving answer from server. With wireshark, I can see that my program correctly sends packet to server AND server responds to it. However, I'm not sure how to get that response to my program.

This is how I send it:

```
    Dim sock As UdpClient
    Dim ip As String = "5.9.204.5"
    Dim port As Int32 = 2302

    Try
        sock = New UdpClient()
        sock.Connect(ip, port)

        Dim Bytes() As Byte = {&HFE, &HFD, &H9, &HFF, &HFF, &HFF, &H1}
        sock.Send(Bytes, Bytes.Length)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Heres screencap of that packet, that server sends to me:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuXAy.png

How I can receive that packet into my program? I plan to query few other servers aswell, which are on same IP but on different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this sample code will help you pal 
[Simple UDP Client Sample](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b/)

Comment: I created a console program that lists everything it receives: http://pastebin.com/v4kd9fzC

It works fine if I directly send packets to localhost. However, what if server which is sending me packets chooses port randomly? As you can see in my screencap in first post, dstport changes everytime I request data.

Comment: may this example will guide you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx